# Hypothesis for Umbrian letter ers pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation, alphabet, consonants, italic-languages, umbrian

Umbrian epichoric alphabet (that is, locally adapted from Etruscan alphabet) has a consonant , called *ers* in Unicode Old Italic scripts references. You can see an example of usage of such letter in the sentence I reproduce below, which appears often in Iguvine tablet I. This sentence is translated in the book *Le tavole iguvine* by Augusto Ancillotti and Romolo Cerri (edizioni Jama Perugia, 1997) as "preghi sulle carni e sui prodotti della terra", that is, "pray over the meats and the products of the earth". You can see the letter  in the word 1, that means "over the meats":

> ::1:1

I've used the Unicode standard symbols, but in Iguvine tablet I, the aspect of the symbol  is

[image]

the one of the symbol  is

[image]

and  looks this way:

[image]

I've reproduced the images of these letters from the above cited book.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbrian_language), letter

> represents an unknown sound

but such statement is based on [Buck's grammar](https://archive.org/details/grammarofoscanum00buckuoft/page/n4/mode/1up), which is from 1904. I believe probably lots of things have happened since the publication of Buck's grammar, so I wonder if there is any hypothesis on how this letter was pronounced. I've seen it's phonetically transcribed as [r̥] on [omniglot.com website](https://www.omniglot.com/writing/umbrian.htm), but I don't know if such site is reliable. So, it's believed that it probably had the voiceless alveolar trill sound [r̥]?

Answer (score 5):

According to Rex Wallace, writing a chapter on the Sabellian languages for the *Cambridge Encyclopedia of the World's Ancient Languages*, "[d]elta was used for a voiced fricative /ẓ/ (ř) rather than the voiced stop /d/, which was represented by tau". He later clarifies that he means a voiced retroflex fricative (IPA `ʐ`); in his view, Umbrian had three sibilants, IPA `/s ʃ ʐ/`.

This is a truly strange inventory; the main evidence for it comes from words attested in both the Umbrian and Latin alphabets, like *te**ř**a* ~ *di**rs**a* "he should give". Historically, it came from Proto-Italic intervocalic **d*, and intervocalic **l* next to a front vowel, which is probably why Wallace claims it was voiced. But the fact that it's written with *rs* rather than *rz* in the Latin alphabet makes me think it could have been a voiceless `/ʂ/` instead. (Or, to put it differently, that Umbrian had no voicing distinctions in its fricatives.)

He cites Meiser 1986:213 ("Lautgeschichte der umbrischen Sprache") which may provide more information.

Answer (score 4):

I see no strong reason to reconstruct **ř** as a voiceless alveolar trill. Diachronically, it developed from voiced sounds:

> reconstructed *-V*d*V- and *-V*l*V<sub>[+front]</sub>- sequences are continued as (⟨**ř**⟩ and) ⟨*rs*⟩ (e.g., **kalētōd* > Umb. **kařetu** [Ib 33], **kařitu** [III 21], *carsitu* [VIa 17, VIIa 43] [fut.imp.3sg] ‘to call’). Also, *-V*d*V*s*- is continued as ⟨**řs**⟩, ⟨**rs**⟩, or ⟨*rs*⟩ when the vowel preceding **s* undergoes syncope

("[Umbrian ⟨*rs*⟩ and ⟨*rf*⟩: A synchronic and diachronic puzzle](https://brill.com/view/journals/ieul/9/1/article-p203_7.xml?language=en)", Teigo Onishi, 26 Nov 2021, in *Indo-European Linguistics*)

"[The matter of voice - the Umbrian perspective](https://crewsproject.files.wordpress.com/2020/02/10-tikkanen-ed.pdf)", by Karin W. Tikkanen (chapter 10 in *Understanding Relations between Scripts II: Early alphabets,* edited by Philip J. Boyes and Philippa M. Steele), characterizes the change of /d/ to **ř** as a spirantization (page 186, 191) and sonorization (page 192).

It seems plausible that it could have been a voiced fricative, as mentioned in Draconis's answer, although that seems awkward to use in clusters like **řs** and **řt**.

"[The  Treebank](http://www.lrec-conf.org/proceedings/lrec2022/workshops/LT4HALA/pdf/2022.lt4hala2022-1.6.pdf)", by Mathieu Dehouck (2022) describes it as "a kind alveolar fricative trill" (page 39).

Comment: If it's reconstructed as a fricative trill that would also explain the transcription ř, which is used for that (afaik) unique sound in Czech.

Comment: All your references are really very interesting: thanks a lot! It's a curious thing to observe how Poultney translation sometimes differs from that of Ancillotti and Cerri. Even **habina** (acc. pl.) is understood as "lamb" by Tikkanen, who cites Untermann's *Wörterbuch des Oskisch-Umbrischen* (2000), whereas in Ancillotti and Cerri it's "scrofe da monta", that is, "breeding sows".